# changing dump.pm2 settings

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have installed a nodejs app running under pm2. When running it keeps going to an external proxy.

At the linux command prompt

```
 echo $http_proxy
```

shows nothing.

However if I go to ./.pm2/dump.pm2 I see multiple entries for http_proxy

```
{
     "env": {
         "NODE_ENV": "production",
         "http_proxy": "http://179.114.70.16:8080",
         "https_proxy": "http://179.114.70.16:8080",
         ...
     },
     "http_proxy": "http://179.114.70.16:8080",
     "https_proxy": "http://179.114.70.16:8080",
     ...
 }
```

Can I edit the dump file and remove them and reload?

What happens if I just use pm2 save now? Will it update the environment variables saved in the dump file?

This is a semi production machine so I don't want to be doing too much trial and error.

Gina

Comment: We just edited the file and rebooted. Everything appears fine. We look after installing the next pm2 app to see of the proxy setting comes back for that app.